# NDK build reporting file doesn't exist on an existing file

Tags: android, c, android-ndk

I'm trying to build [mediastreamer2](https://github.com/bitzeppelin/mediastreamer2) for Android. I'm using cygwin on Windows 7. While running ndk-build I get the following errors:

---

```
$ ../../android-ndk-r6b-windows/android-ndk-r6b/ndk-build
Gdbserver      : [arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3] libs/armeabi/gdbserver
Gdbsetup       : libs/armeabi/gdb.setup
Compile arm    : mediastreamer2 <= mscommon.c
cc1.exe: error: /cygdrive/c/Users/SN/workspace/hello-jni/jni/src/../build/android/libmediastreamer2_AndroidConfig.h: No such file or directory
In file included from C:/Users/SN/workspace/hello-jni/jni/src/mscommon.c:28: 
C:/Users/SN/workspace/hello-jni/jni/src/../include/mediastreamer2/mscommon.h:22:
23: error: ortp/ortp.h: No such file or directory
In file included from C:/Users/SN/workspace/hello-jni/jni/src/../include/mediastreamer2/msfilter.h:24,
                 from C:/Users/SN/workspace/hello-jni/jni/src/mscommon.c:29:
C:/Users/SN/workspace/hello-jni/jni/src/../include/mediastreamer2/msqueue.h:22:28: error: ortp/str_utils.h: No such file or directory
In file included from C:/Users/SN/workspace/hello-jni/jni/src/../include/mediastreamer2/msfilter.h:24,
                 from C:/Users/SN/workspace/hello-jni/jni/src/mscommon.c:29:
```

---

However, `/cygdrive/c/Users/SN/workspace/hello-jni/jni/src/../build/android/libmediastreamer2_AndroidConfig.h` is an existing file. Any ideas on how to fix this?

The Android.mk file is [here](https://github.com/bitzeppelin/mediastreamer2/blob/master/build/android/Android.mk), and I've added the following lines to it at the bottom before I ran it.

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := mediastreamer2wrapper
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := mediastreamer2
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only way I found to build it was to do it on Linux. Cygwin didn't work.